# ¿Cómo iniciar sesion con curl php en un sitio web con este tipo de autenticación?

Tags: php, curl, autenticación

Estoy trabajando con curl php, y deseo acceder a una web con el tipo de autenticación que muestro en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$login="https://pagoselectricaribe.facture.co/Login?returnurl=%2f";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=____WebKitFormBoundaryA2xcZYchkSX"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"txtPassword=123345456&txtUsername=correo@gmail.com"); 
$content = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($content);
curl_close($ch);
```

Esto es lo que me resulta de ejecutar el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: las credenciales al ingresarlas manualmente en la ventana si accedo normal a la web, necesito hacerlo desde curl. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay una CURLOPT para autenticación http básica:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '123345456:correo@gmail.com');
```

Van separados por `:`.

Comment: Muchas ! gracias, ya lo solucione con esto

Comment: Hola, cómo hago para recuperar en el controlador las variables que estoy pasando en CURLOPT_USERPWD o por CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?? Estoy pasando variables de una url a otra con curl php y no se cómo recuperarlas.  Ayuda por favor

Comment: @Virginia: Si no funciona `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` te recomedaría que abras una pregunta nueva con mas detalles.

Comment: @Sal gracias por responder, publicaré otra pregunta porque no me funcionó